# h1 Tooltip is Much Higher Than on an h4

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I have a `tooltip` and I have it on an `h1` and an `h4`. Here is what it looks like on the `h4`:

[image: h4 tooltip picture]

And here is what an `h1` looks like:

[image: h1 tooltip picture]

The `tooltip` is much higher up on the `h1` than the `h4`. Basically, I want both of them to look exactly the same.

Here is my code:

```css
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.tooltip:hover {
 cusor: pointer; 
}
.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
}
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
&nbsp;
<p></p>
&nbsp;
<p></p>
&nbsp;
<p></p>
&nbsp;
<p></p>
<center>
<!-- h4 tooltip -->
<div class = "tooltip"><span id = "htmlHub" class = "contact">programs</span><span class="tooltiptext">Go to the Programs tab</span></div>
&nbsp;
<!-- h1 tooltip -->
<div id = "rockPaperScissors" class = "programs tooltip"><h1>Rock Paper Scissors</h1><span class="tooltiptext">Go to the Rock Paper Scissors program</span></div>
</center>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly because the `h1` has a large top/bottom `margin`, but also affecting the position is the `line-height`. To have it match the way it displays over your `span`, just set the `margin` to `0` and optionally, the `line-height` to `1` or whatever works for your layout.

```css
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
}
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.tooltip:hover {
 cusor: pointer; 
}
.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
}
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
&nbsp;
<p></p>
&nbsp;
<p></p>
&nbsp;
<p></p>
&nbsp;
<p></p>
<center>
<!-- h4 tooltip -->
<div class = "tooltip"><span id = "htmlHub" class = "contact">programs</span><span class="tooltiptext">Go to the Programs tab</span></div>
&nbsp;
<!-- h1 tooltip -->
<div id = "rockPaperScissors" class = "programs tooltip"><h1>Rock Paper Scissors</h1><span class="tooltiptext">Go to the Rock Paper Scissors program</span></div>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using both `left` and `bottom` as percentages, I'd recommend simply using a negative pixel-based `top`. I've gone with `-35px` in my example.

Note that depending on where exactly you want the tooltip to sit horizontally, you will need to use `margin-left`. I've just gone with `-100px` here, but you might want to make that relative.

This will make the `<h1>` tooltip slightly higher than the `<h4>` tooltip:

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  /*visibility: hidden;*/
  width: 150px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: -100px;
  font-size: 16px;
  top: -35px;
}

.tooltip:hover {
  cusor: pointer;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
&nbsp;
<p></p>
&nbsp;
<p></p>
&nbsp;
<p></p>
&nbsp;
<p></p>
<center>
  <!-- h4 tooltip -->
  <div class="tooltip"><span id="htmlHub" class="contact">Programs</span><span class="tooltiptext">Go to the Programs tab</span></div>
  &nbsp;
  <!-- h1 tooltip -->
  <div id="rockPaperScissors" class="programs tooltip">
    <h1>Rock Paper Scissors</h1><span class="tooltiptext">Go to the Rock Paper Scissors program</span></div>
</center>
```

Optionally, you can use the `line-height` attribute to override the differing line heights for the headings. Setting this to `0` for both elements ensures that the tooltip will remain at the **same** height for both headings:

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  /*visibility: hidden;*/
  width: 150px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: -100px;
  font-size: 16px;
  top: -35px;
}

.tooltip:hover {
  cusor: pointer;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}

h1,
h4 {
  line-height: 0;
}
```

```html
&nbsp;
<p></p>
&nbsp;
<p></p>
&nbsp;
<p></p>
&nbsp;
<p></p>
<center>
  <!-- h4 tooltip -->
  <div class="tooltip"><span id="htmlHub" class="contact">Programs</span><span class="tooltiptext">Go to the Programs tab</span></div>
  &nbsp;
  <!-- h1 tooltip -->
  <div id="rockPaperScissors" class="programs tooltip">
    <h1>Rock Paper Scissors</h1><span class="tooltiptext">Go to the Rock Paper Scissors program</span></div>
</center>
```

Hope this helps! :)